# 特定のuitableviewcellのリロード時にcell内のawakeFromNibが呼ばれない

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

お世話になります
そもそも実装が間違ってるのかもしれないのですが、質問させてください

uitableviewcellで使うデータを別画面で作成して戻ってきた際に、特定のcellだけ更新作業を走らせようとしてるのですが、どうもうまく行きません

```
//こだわりだけリロード
func updateOtherKodawari(){
    let indexpath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 5)
    self.appdelegate.shotvm.readData()
    self.menuview.beginUpdates()
    self.menuview.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexpath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
    self.menuview.endUpdates()
}
```

ここだけリロードさせたくしておりまして

```
case 5:
        let cell: OtherKodawariCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OtherKodawariCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OtherKodawariCell
        return cell
```

こんな感じで、cellは書いてあります。
cell内では以下のようにしてありまして

```
import UIKit

class OtherKodawariCell: UITableViewCell {

weak var appdelegate:AppDelegate!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    self.appdelegate = AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate()
    setUp()
}

func setUp(){

    var x = 0
    let top_margin_x = 8
    let margin_x = 10
    var y = 5
    let margin_y = 5
    let screen = UIScreen.mainScreen()
    let width = Int((screen.bounds.size.width-30)/2)
    let height = 20

    let ary_other_name_kodawari = self.appdelegate.appCode.dic_cond?.objectForKey("ary_other_name_kodawari") as? NSArray

    let ary_other_kodawari = self.appdelegate.appCode.dic_cond?.objectForKey("ary_other_kodawari") as? NSArray

    //空の場合は終了
    if ary_other_name_kodawari != nil{
        if ary_other_name_kodawari!.count == 0{
            return
        }
    }else{
        return
    }


    if let array = ary_other_kodawari{
        var i = 0
        for code in array{

            if i%2 == 0 && i != 0{
                y += margin_y+height
                x = top_margin_x
            }else if i == 0{
                x += top_margin_x
            }
            let text: AnyObject? = ary_other_name_kodawari?.objectAtIndex(i)
            if let font = UIFont(name: "HiraKakuProN-W6", size: 10){
                let size:CGSize = text!.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:font])
                let tagview = TagView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height))
                tagview.setUp(text! as! String, withfont: font, withsize: size)
                self.addSubview(tagview)
                x += width
            }
            x += margin_x
            i += 1
        }
    }
}


override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

自分のイメージだと、cellがcellのリロードでcellが再生成されて、cell内のawakeFromNibが呼ばれるのかなと思っているのですが、違うのでしょうか

よろしくお願い致します

Comment: `awakefromxib`を`awakefromNib`に訂正させていただきました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 自分のイメージだと、cellがcellのリロードでcellが再生成されて、cell内のawakefromxibが呼ばれるのかなと思っているのですが、違うのでしょうか

cell の生成は重い処理であり、`UITableView` ではなるべくそれを避けるために、表示中の cell は再生成しないようになっていると思います。また、スクロールで画面外に出た cell も開放せずに保持しておき、再利用するという仕組みになっています。

設定にもよりますが、いったん `UITableView` が表示されてから、新たに cell が生成されることがほとんどない、ということもよくあります。

そのため、cell の生成のタイミングで表示内容を決めていると、リロードしても表示内容は更新されません。

---

いちど使った cell が別の行で使われることもあるので、本来、cell の生成と同時に表示内容を確定させるのではなく、cell には必要なラベルなどを用意するだけにしておき、`tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` でそれに内容を設定する、という設計が期待されています。

`OtherKodawariCell` をそのように変更するのがベストだと思いますが、もっとも簡単な解決策は、この部分で、：

```
case 5:
    let cell: OtherKodawariCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OtherKodawariCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OtherKodawariCell
    return cell
```

`OtherKodawariCell.setUp()` 相当の処理を行うことかな、と思います。

---

ただし、この処理は同じ cell に対して何度も呼ばれることもあるので、`setUp()` のように、「空の場合は終了」するのではなく、不要なビュー等を削除したり、表示内容をリセットしたりする必要があります。

そのために `UITableViewCell` には、いちど表示された cell が再利用される前に呼ばれる `prepareForReuse()` メソッドが用意されていますので、これをオーバライドして、必要な処理を書かれることをおすすめします。

Comment: なるほど！そういうことなのですね、ありがとうございます！

Comment: 解決しました！
ありがとうございます。